# Need to get the value which is not available in DOM element

Tags: selenium

[website](http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/slider.php)

I want to get the value of highlighted field for the validation purpose. but the problem is it's not available in DOM element. Could anyone please guide me on this.

I am using selenium with C# for this automation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you want is accessible via JavaScript.

Devtools tells me the element is an `input` with `id=amount`:

[image: devtools on page]

You can then use the console to iterigate the element:

[image: console]

To run this in selenium you use a javascript executor.

You've not specified which language you're working with... so...

In Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
var myValue = js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('amount').value");
```

in Python:

```
myValue = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('amount').value")
```

in c#:

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
var myValue = js.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementById('amount').value");
```

One last note - that element and slider is located within an iframe. You may need to switch frames in order to access it. Let me know if you need support with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help....I had issue with this part, rest is working fine.